# How can I prevent wine from disabling/shutting off my "secondary" monitor?

Tags: wine, resolution, monitor

I'm running my computer using dual monitors. As when I am gaming I call my right monitor my "primary" and my left the "secondary" because I've set my PC up to where fullscreen games load on my right monitor, which is the way that I want it. But the default way wine works, my "Secondary"(left) monitor when I'm "gaming" is disabled by wine, which is something I extremely dislike and will not put up with. What I want is for wine to stop disabling my "secondary"(left) monitor and allow a way to gain access to my left monitor even when I have fullscreen games running on my right monitor.

I have heard ways to "bypass" this screen disabling problem is by enabling the "emulate a virtual desktop" option. The problem I have with using that option to disable wine from disabling my "secondary" monitor is that (unless there is a more updated version of wine) wine will only allow me to set one "resolution" to set games at. so basically if I'm running a game that has a smaller resolution than the "virtual desktop" then it basically run my game(s) in windowed mode instead of stretching the game to fit my screen's resolution/virtual desktop resolution.

Is there any way to disable wine from disabling/turning off the monitor my "fullscreen" games running in wine and allow games that are smaller than the resolution of wine's "virtual desktop" to automatically stretch to "fullscreen"?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to fix this problem? Don't just leave me hanging here...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

http://laviefrugale.blogspot.com/2011/08/re-enable-second-monitor-in-linux-after.html

`xrandr --auto` didn't work, it reenabled the second monitor but it was a clone of the first. But I used the command `xrandr --auto --output DFP2 --right-of DFP1` and the other monitor was enabled properly (single desktop spanned across monitors). Might have to swap the two if your second logical monitor is on the left.